# How to display graphs in multiple pages/tabs in R Shiny Dashboard?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, shiny

I am trying to create a Shiny Dashboard which contains Plots also. The plots depend on the type of Inputs that the user chooses. For example lets take the Data as below.

```
d <-
data.frame(
year = c(1995, 1995, 1995, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1997, 1997, 1997),
Product_Name = c(
  "Table",
  "Chair",
  "Bed",
  "Table",
  "Chair",
  "Bed",
  "Table",
  "Chair",
  "Bed"
),
Product_desc = c("X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Z", "Z"),
Cost = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
)
```

This is the below code which i am using to generate the graphs. For each year. Where the each year data is displayed in Facets by using facet_wrap.

```
d %>% 
ggplot(aes(Product_Name, Cost)) + 
geom_col(aes(fill = Product_desc), position = position_dodge(preserve = "single")) + 
facet_wrap(~year, scales = "free_x", strip.position = "bottom") +
theme(strip.placement = "outside") + 
theme_bw()
```

Instead of the year data getting displayed in facets I want the data to be displayed in a separate page in the shiny dashboard or in the separate tabs.

For example if the user chooses only 2 years then first graph should be displayed in one page and second graph should be displayed in the next page. For example as shown in the below image.

[image]

Depending upon the number of years selected there should be equal number of pages/tabs displaying the graph for each year.

Can someone please suggest me on how to proceed further.

Kindly let me know in case of any other information required.

Comment: What I usually do is create an reactive variable that would count the number of selected years, then create a function that would hide/show certain plot and page based on selecting.. you can use shinyjs package and show/hide tabs, while you prepare the plots in advance. The other option would be to create a blank tab and then create plots with renderUI command + your function and then display the tab.

Comment: @JacobJacox Thanks for the Comment. I will surly give it a try and let you know how it went. ! If possible can you please share any example code or shiny dashboard which i can look in to ?

Comment: I cannot share the code (legally) sorry, but if u post example code and where it went wrong I think I would be able to help.